# TFS Sharepoint installation directory

Tags: tfs, sharepoint-2010

We have installed TFS sharepoint and the physical path of the iis site is on following location "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14"

Virtual directory:SharePoint - 80\ | Physicalpath:C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14

I wanted to move the site out of system drive and use some other drive on the server, can it be moved or need to be reinstall from scratch? Also if it's installed on other than system drive will it works normally? 
Please provide some insights. Thank you!

Comment: It's worth noting that Sharepoint integration is deprecated in modern versions of TFS. If you're installing Sharepoint purely for the TFS integration, I'd recommend skipping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that you can just move the site location. Some step for moving of web application you may find here https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28922547/Move-sharepoint-and-sharepoint-database-to-a-different-server.html. In my opinion you have to do next steps (**you have to test they first on test environment**):

1. Uninstall TFS SharePoint extensions.
2. Uninstall SharePoint.
3. Backup SP Content DB (this is main DB).
4. Install SP to new location and create new web application.
5. Remove new Content DB with SP Central Admin and mount old DB with command "Mount-SPContentDatabase  -DatabaseServer  -WebApplication http://intranet/sitename"
6. Install and configure TFS SharePoint extensions.